# Using a Web Deployment Project for deployment in TFS 2010

Tags: tfsbuild, web-deployment-project, web-deployment

I build a VST 2010 solution in TFS Build 2010. The solution contains a web application that is automatically deployed using MSBuild Arguments in the Build's definition like

/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
...

Now, I want to PreCompile the Views of the Web application before deployment (to disable the updatable 'feature' of the views).
I created an Web Deployment Project within the solution and installed the Web Deployment Projects at the build server.

My Questions:
How can I force the web deployment project to be build?
How can I tell the build process, to deploy the files (and views) generated by the deployment project and not by the web application project itself?
At the end, I want to not updatable views on the webserver.